# For $n\geq 2$, any continuous map $f:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow S^2$ induces the zero map on $H_2(*)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am working through an old qualifying exam from another university.  My course did not cover as much material as what is on this test (e.g. we did not cover cohomology).  So I am just working through the problems which look like fair game for the material covered in my course. I tried the following problem (because it looks like I should now how to do it), and I am very stuck on it:

For $n\geq 2$, any continuous map $f:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow S^2$ induces the zero map on $H_2(*)$.

I know that $H_2(\mathbb{C}P^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$ as well.  So it is not obvious yet that $f_*$ is the zero map.  I tried looking at the long exact sequence for the pair $(\mathbb{C}P^n, S^2)$ and computed the relative homology groups; all of the seemingly relevant ones are trivial (i.e. $i=1,2,3$).  So the long exact sequence doesn't seem to give me any more information.  I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: What map does it induce on $H^2$?

Comment: Dang, does this question involve cohomology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cohomology ring of $\Bbb{CP}^n$ is $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^{n+1})$, with $|x|=2$. Any map $f: \Bbb{CP}^n \to S^2$ induces zero on cohomology when $n>1$, because if $z \in H^2(S^2)$ is a generator, then $0 = f^*(z^2) = f^*(z)^2$, so $f^*(z)$ must be zero.

Now use the fact that the universal coefficient theorem is natural to see that the induced map on $H_2$ is also zero. (I don't really want to draw the diagram.)

EDIT: Here's the above, stated differently. Let $f: S^2 \to S^2$ be a map of nonzero degree. I claim you cannot extend $f$ to $\Bbb{CP}^2$. For $\Bbb{CP}^2$ is obtained from $S^2$ by attaching a 4-cell along the Hopf map $\eta: S^3 \to S^2$, it's only possible to extend the map over the 4-cell if $f\eta$ is null-homotopic; but $f\eta = n[\eta] \in \pi_3(S^2) \cong \Bbb Z$, where the Hopf map is a generator of this homotopy group.

The reason these are the same answer is because the way one often proves that $n\eta$ is not null-homotopic is by calculating the cohomology ring structure on $X_n = S^2 \cup_{n\eta} D^4$ and seeing that it's nontrivial.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a nice solution without using cohomology?  I haven't covered it yet.

Comment: @1234 While I certainly can't falsify the possibility, I doubt it. I wrote a different answer here, probably still out of the realm of reasonability if you've only learned about homology.

Comment: @1234: The approach here really does make the most sense. The obstruction to having a nontrivial map comes from the ring structure on $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^n)$, which doesn't appear if you just look at homology. (It's a bit odd that homology is usually introduced separately and before cohomology, since the latter has a ring structure and often appears earlier in de Rham cohomology.)

Comment: Dear Mike, could you please give some details/general statements  on how to pass from cohomology to homology,  even without drawing any diagrams! I think I can do that but I'm using that homology groups are free in the present  case, and this looks like overkill.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg We have the exact sequence from $0 \to \text{Hom}(H_2(M);\Bbb Z) \to H^2(M) \to \text{Ext}(H_1(M);\Bbb Z)$. I'm now invoking that these manifolds are simply connected, so $H_1 = 0$. I suppose this is where you use freeness? I don't find this too strong a condition. Then the map on $H^2$ is precisely the dual of the map on $H_2$, which as we saw was zero.

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks for your instantaneous (despite relativity theory!)  answer. Yes, I had thought of your exact sequence but it does not solve the problem in general because $H^2(M;\mathbb Z)=Hom (H_2(M);\mathbb Z)=0$  does not imply $H_2(M)=0$ and similar problems for maps between cohomology groups dual to maps between homology groups.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Aha, fair enough. I have assumed here a computation of the homology groups $H_2(M;\Bbb Z)$ for both of these spaces; I assume we have all the invariants of the spaces and are now interested in the maps involved.

Comment: Dear Mike: right, so probably freeness is indeed needed since we want to prove that an abelian group morphism is zero knowing only that its transpose (=dual) is zero. Anyway +1 for your answer.